# 2-D scatter plot of image PC(s)

Tags: image, python-3.x, matplotlib

I need to apply PCA on images to make a 2-D scatter plots of first two PCs and identify regions of high densities, which are further treated as ROI (regions of interest). Basically, it's PCA for image segmentation.
However, I am new to matplotlib and I can't get my head around how to plot the PCs? 
Here is my initial code, where I load and normalize several images (by the way, is Histogram Equalization the right way to normalize images before PCA?) and try to perform PCA on one of them:

```
from skimage import io
from skimage import exposure
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA 
images = io.imread_collection(image_path)
images_equalized = []
for i in range(len(images)):
    images_equalized.append(exposure.equalize_hist(images[i]))
pca = PCA(n_components=2)
im_pca = pca.fit_transform(images_equalized[35])
```

Now, how to make a scatterplot?
`plt.imshow(im_pca)`
`plt.show()`
Image shape is (508, 636)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pca.fit_transform()` returns an new array of shape (n_samples, n_components). This is the scores data which you can plot as a biplot scatter.

The scores for each component are in the second dimension of the array, so you can index into the array and plot as follows.

```
im_pca = pca.fit_transform(images_equalized[35])

plt.scatter(im_pca[:,0], im_pca[:,1])
```